# python question regarding re.search and indexing

Tags: python

Im new to python and coding and im trying to understand how re.search and indexing works.

below is what I have so far and I want physical_state to equal what comes after the Completion: (in this case it is success) but I dont really understand how the match.group(1) and re.search works.

```
import ops         # Import the OPS module.
import sys         # Import the sys module.
import re

# Subscription processing function
def ops_condition (o): 
    status, err_str = o.timer.relative("tag",10)
    return status

def ops_execute (o):
    handle, err_desp = o.cli.open()
    print("OPS opens the process of command:",err_desp)
    result, n11, n21 = o.cli.execute(handle,"return")
    result, n11, n21 = o.cli.execute(handle,"dis nqa results test-instance sla 1 | i Completion:")  
    match = re.search(r"Completion:", result)

    if not match:
        print("Could not determine the state.")
            return 0  # Look into what the return values mean.

    physical_state = match.group(1)  # Gets the first group from the match.
    print (physical_state)
    result = o.cli.close(handle)
    return 0
```

output of `result, n11, n21 = o.cli.execute(handle,"dis nqa results test-instance sla 1 | i Completion:")`

```
   Completion:success                   RTD OverThresholds number: 0
   Completion:success                   RTD OverThresholds number: 0
   Completion:success                   RTD OverThresholds number: 0
   Completion:success                   RTD OverThresholds number: 0
   Completion:success                   RTD OverThresholds number: 0
```

error when run

```
<setup>('OPS opens the process of command:', 'success')

    Oct 18 2018 06:12:57+00:00 setup %%01OPSA/3/OPS_RESULT_EXCEPTION(l)[410]:Script is test3.py, current event is tag, instance is 1381216156, exception reason is Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".lib/frame.py", line 114, in <module>
        ret = m.ops_execute(o)
      File "flash:$_user/test3.py", line 21, in ops_execute
        physical_state = match.group(1)  # Gets the first group from the match.
    IndexError: no such group
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Match groups (except group 0) are defined by parentheses in the regular expression

Comment: of course, thanks this has done the trick I changed the line to match = re.search(r"Completion:(\S+)", result) Thanks